# How to avoid smart pointers delete[] exception with custom STL vector class?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, vector

I have just ended implementing custom vector class. Most informations have been taken from https://secweb.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs361/web/website/Lectures/vectorImpl/page/vectorImpl.html

When I want to create a vector of unique_ptr, after closing the application, exception is thrown and call stack leads me to .clear() method.

`size_t m_capacity, m_size;`
`T* m_data`

```
inline void clear() 
{
    if (m_data) {
        m_size = 0;
        m_capacity = 0;
        delete[] m_data;
        m_data = nullptr;
    }
}
```

problem with smart pointers disappears when I remove `delete[] m_data`, but then there is a huge leak.

```
template<typename T>
inline void vector<T>::push_back(const T& value)
{
    // If array is full, reserve more data
    if (m_size == m_capacity) {
        reserve(CalculateCapacity(m_size + 1));
    }

    memcpy(&m_data[m_size], &value, sizeof(value));

    ++m_size;
}

template<typename T>
inline size_t vector<T>::CalculateCapacity(size_t capacity) const
{
    size_t new_capacity = m_capacity ? (m_capacity + m_capacity) : 8;
    return new_capacity > capacity ? new_capacity : capacity;
}

template<typename T>
inline void vector<T>::reserve(size_t newCapacity)
{
    // Return if we have enough space
    if (newCapacity <= m_capacity) {
        return;
    }

    // Allocate new data area
    T* newData = new T[newCapacity];

    if (m_data) {
        // Copy old data
        memcpy(newData, m_data, m_size);
        // Delete old data
        delete[] m_data;
    }

    // Setup bigger array
    m_data = newData;
    m_capacity = newCapacity;
}
```

How can I get rid of this exception while push_backing?

Comment: What is `m_data` ? provide MCVE.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you use `memcpy()` to copy the values into and around the container. Copying an object with `memcpy()` is *only* valid when dealing with an object of [*trivially copyable type*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable). `std::unique_ptr()` is *not* trivially copyable. It's not even copyable. You will need to add support for movable types to your container if you want to support `std::unique_ptr` as an element type.

What will basically happen when you `push_back()` an `std::unique_ptr` now is that the contents of the `unique_ptr` are copied into the container. But as soon as the original `unique_ptr` goes out of scope, it will delete whatever it was pointing to because ownership was not transferred into the container. In general, behavior is undefined because you did not construct a valid `unique_ptr` object inside your container. But in practice, when you `delete[]` the contents of your container, it will still just call the destructors of all the `unique_ptr` elements, which will try to delete the objects they are pointing to. However, the original objects already have been deleted at that point…

You can use [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) to check whether a type is trivially copyable. So a first step would be to have a `static_assert()` that triggers a compile error when someone tries to use your container with an unsupported type.

To support moveable types, add a `push_back(T&&)` that moves the new element into the container instead of making a copy. And use the `std::move()` algorithm to move existing elements to the new buffer in your `reserve()` method.

Comment: This answer could be improved by suggesting how to do the move. The algorithm `std::move` might be useful...

Comment: @Michael Kenzel `...to the new buffer in your resize() method.` Resize?

Comment: @PeteBecker indeed, I added some more information to my answer above.

Comment: @Pain I guess I meant to write reserve…fixed